# Entity framework migrations with a modular application

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im building a modular application. Some modules will be extensions on other modules. Every module is having its own project structure with services etc. Though some entities are shared between them.

This is the structure:

```
Shared
    - Entity A
    - Entity B
    - Entity C
Module A
   Entities
    - Entity D
    - Entity E
    - Entity F
   Dbcontext 
     - Ent A, B, C, D, E, F
Module B
   Entities
    - Entity X
    - Entity Y
    - Entity Z
   Dbcontext 
     - Ent A, B, C, X, Y, Z
```

All tables are in a shared database (this is because it could be in the feature that there will be a module that has entities A, D, X).

How can I migrate database changes with entityframework? What I would like is as long as it is a extension to the tables (so no destuction) that it just adds the tables and fields. If there is any destruction I'm ok with doing them manual.

P.S. Seperating the databases is in this scenario not an option due to performance reasons of joins and stuff.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but the problem is even more complex than you suggest.  Even if you don't allow destruction, you run the risk of modules using the same column for different things, or perhaps having two tables the same name.  Look at how Orchard CMS does things, it might help you with ideas.

Comment: I realise the risks. Those are due to the fact that it is a small team acceptable. We did this already with nhibernate, now we need it with entity framework.